# Ensuring completion block is executed on the main thread

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I have the following code. Do I need the second `dispatch_async` or the completion block will be executed on the main thread because the func2 is called on the main thread?

```
- (void)func1
{
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^() {
      [self func2];
   });
}

- (void)func2
{
   [self.object someLongNetworkOperationWithCompletionBlock: ^() {
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^() {
          // Update some UI elements here
       });
   }]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends entirely on the implementation of the actual method `someLongNetworkOperationWithCompletionBlock:`. Whatever queue it calls the parameter block on is the queue it will run on. If you are executing code on a background queue in that method and want it to always call the block on main, put the GCD call in that method directly.

The implementation of a method that does this would look something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^()
                 {
                     // execute code on background queue
                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^()
                                    {
                                        // call completion block on main
                                        completion();
                                    });
                 });
```

Comment: So even if func2 is always executed on the main thread, completion block potentially can be called NOT on the main thread?

Comment: The block will run on whatever queue it is called from. If you call it while executing on a background queue, it will run on a background queue. The queue that the method itself is called from will have no bearing if you execute code on another queue inside it.